# Ubuntu 22.4 Crashes Every time I start LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice, crash

I have uninstalled and installed again LibreOffice. However every time I start LibreOffice Writer Ubuntu 22 freezes and I cannot move the mouse. Is there anything else I can try? I
am getting getting ready to switch to Apache OpenOffice?

Comment: Did you [check (and reset) your user profile](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile)?